# How to deal with missing/delayed server responses in synchronized requests?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a client-server architecture, where the client sends synchronized requests to the server over a socket. The client resends the request regularly after a certain timeout (to prevent the client blocking the thread, in the case the request never reaches the server). After a certain number of tries the client continues (even if no response from the server).
However, in this scenario it could happen, that the server sends the response after the client continued, which would leave the client having wrong state information (since the client assumes that the request was never processed by the server).

How can I make sure, that the client can continue after a timeout-period, but at the same time assure that there's no state difference at server- and client-side?

Comment: Is rejection an option? Based on some id or a request timestamp?

Comment: @aksappy nope. Maybe may logic is flawed. Maybe the client really needs to block the thread indefinately if it can't continue continue well without having a guarantee about the current server-state. Can't wrap my head around how scenarios like this are usually handled.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me. Y is the devised solution to the unknown problem X, only that Y does not work. Please provide the actual problem X you are trying to solve. It is really necessary for X that the client knows that the server has never send a response? Isn't it sufficient that the client knows that it never received a response from the server within a specific time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, this is an unsolvable problem. There will always be a chance for inconsistency between the client and server. The best thing you can do is try to repair the inconsistency when more information becomes available. In your case, once the response from the server arrives, the client can update its view of the state. However, it is also possible for the response from the server to be lost permanently. In that case, it can be pragmatic to have the client periodically try to reconcile its state with that of the server.

In distributed computing literature, this is known as the [Two Generals' Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem).